# Number of pending edits hardly readable

Tags: bug, feature-request

This is how it shows

[image]

and at least on my monitor I can hardly tell the number from the orange background. Can a more contrasting color be used?

By the way, is this readable for others?

**edit**
Screenshot is from Firefox, but I installed Chrome (slow!!) and on both Chrome and Internet Exploder (the rectangle) it's equally badly readable.

Comment: totally agreed .

Comment: I can read it OK on my monitor. I certainly can't object to more contrast though. Interestingly, mine shows up as a rectangle, not a circle as your screen shot shows.

Comment: @Olin - that's odd. Maybe different CSS for different browsers? Mine is Firefox 13.0.1

Comment: On Stack Overflow, I get a rounded rectangle.

Comment: @endolith: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 13.0.1 ---

Comment: It's a Firefox issue (or a problem with the CSS that affects Firefox) then. It renders fine on Chrome. @Olin is probably using a browser that doesn't support CSS rounded corners, which is why the box renders as a rectangle.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I bet he uses Netscape Navigator 3.0. You know that he's an old man ;-). Me too, next week :-(

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I can't tell about SO, for lack of reputation there.

Comment: @stevenvh: Hmm. Can you try this site in Chrome to see if that is indeed the problem? I can't see the review bubble on this site for lack of reputation, but since all SO sites use the same platform, I assume it works in Chrome (did for SO).

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I added to my question that it looks the same in Chrome, also in IE, BTW.

Comment: Ok, it's a CSS issue then. I took a look at the source and the code required to make the text white is there. So I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Should this be labeled as a bug instead of a feature request? I agree that this is an annoyingly difficult combination of colors.

Comment: clearly says `7`. I don't agree with your 'problem'.

Comment: CRT's often have a better picture when it comes to badly contrasting colors. Maybe it was designed on a CRT?

Comment: @jippie - *I* may have contrast problems with my monitor, but *you* seem to have accuracy problems in your arithmetic unit. ;-)

Comment: Don't know: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EfQ6O.png ;o)